# How do I rotate my AWS IAM user access and secret key using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-access-policy

We are using the Python AWS SDK (`boto3`) to connect to S3.

We have a static access and secret token, however my network is not safe.

I can't use another network for sending requests so is there a way to change the access and secret keys after every request?

I can save a new token in a safe database for sending another request but it's important that after using the token, it expires.

What I'm looking for:

```
send: curl https://aws.endpoint/refresh/token
response: {“new_access_token”:”blablabla”, “new_secret_token”:”blablablabla”}
```

Comment: Are you able to take user input to then generate the token?

Comment: This sounds like an https://xyproblem.info/ - if the network is not secure, then why send the request in the first place? Ther requests are SSL encrypted anyway - what is the worry?

Comment: tnx a lot ermiya. actually what i want, is a api, for creating new tokens. only this. are this goal is possible? @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more comprehensive, does that help?

Comment: Thats it. You showed me the way to the gold. TnX :X @ErmiyaEskandary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you must**, you can rotate your keys using a combination of [`iam.create_access_key`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_access_key), [`iam.get_access_key_last_used`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_access_key_last_used), [`iam.update_access_key`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.update_access_key) & [`iam.delete_access_key`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.delete_access_key) API actions.

Keep in mind you can only have a maximum of 2 access keys per user so you will have to create a new one using `create_access_key`, disable/make inactive the current (old) one (`get_access_key_last_used` & `update_access_key`), change your access key to the next one within the application code, and then finally delete the current one `delete_access_key`.

---

However, **AWS access keys are meant to be long-term credentials** for an IAM user or the AWS account root user; you can rotate them on a regular basis but I wouldn't be doing that in the first place in this scenario.

Your optimal solution will depend on the service you are using.

If using EC2 instances to call S3, for example, don't use/embed/pass/read access keys but instead use shortlived temporary security credentials that would be provided by launching the EC2 instance with a role for S3 access.

If you're using this script locally, you can use [AWS Security Token Service (AWS STS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/welcome.html) that enables you to request temporary, limited-privilege credentials for AWS IAM users/federated users (single sign-on etc.). You'd be looking for the [`GetSessionToken`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html#api_getsessiontoken) API operation (Boto3 SDK docs [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_session_token)).

In both cases, the credentials include a security token that indicates when the credentials expire & they are short-lived on purpose to help reduce your risk in case credentials are accidentally exposed.

**Read: [Best practices for managing AWS access keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html)**